# How do I create a triangle using JavaFX?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8, polygon

How can I create a triangle using JavaFX?
I have already tried these but I don't know how to fix it exactly :

```
Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
triangle.getPoints().setAll(
   50, 50,
   60, 60,
   20, 40
);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace  `triangle.getPoints().setAll`.. with `triangle.getPoints().addAll(`

## Explanation:

You are adding 3 points, the x0=50,y0=50 then the x0=60,y0=60  and then x0=20,y0=40, those are the vertices of the triangle...

this represents a triangle like this (Be careful of not plotting a line or a weird figure)

[image]

The following  snippet will generate a polygon like the image below.

```
public class Main extends Application {
      @Override
      public void start(Stage stage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 260, 80);
        stage.setScene(scene);
    
        Group g = new Group();
    
        Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
        polygon.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
            0.0, 0.0,
            20.0, 10.0,
            10.0, 20.0 });
        
        g.getChildren().add(polygon);
        
        scene.setRoot(g);
        stage.show();
      }
    
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
      }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the [Javadoc for Polygon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/toc.htm):

```
Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
polygon.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
    0.0, 0.0,
    20.0, 10.0,
    10.0, 20.0 });
```

It looks like you are missing the `new Double[] {...}`

Comment: I have just add it thank you :) but can you tell me what does these values means ??